# C++ subtract days in string format YYYYMMDD

Tags: c++

I'm struggling a little getting some C++ code to cooperate. Is there a straight forward way to subtract two dates that are strings? I'm trying to get the number of days between them. They are strings, `YYYYMMDD`. Is the Boost library the right direction to go?

Comment: Generally one would use a library routine to convert both to some standard date format (which internally is a day number or seconds since 1970 or whatever) then use other library routines to subtract the two converted date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Boost Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time) can certainly do that even others may suggest "lighter" alternatives.

Here is the example about the *days alive* which does almost exactly your problem (just add a second date parsing):

```
/* Short example that calculates the number of days since user was born.
 * Demonstrates comparisons of durations, use of the day_clock,
 * and parsing a date from a string.
 */

#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int
main() 
{

  using namespace boost::gregorian;
  std::string s;
  std::cout << "Enter birth day YYYY-MM-DD (eg: 2002-02-01): ";
  std::cin >> s;
  try {
    date birthday(from_simple_string(s));
    date today = day_clock::local_day();
    days days_alive = today - birthday;
    days one_day(1);
    if (days_alive == one_day) {
      std::cout << "Born yesterday, very funny" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (days_alive < days(0)) {
      std::cout << "Not born yet, hmm: " << days_alive.days() 
                << " days" <<std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "Days alive: " << days_alive.days() << std::endl;
    }

  }
  catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Bad date entered: " << s << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of several parsing routines, yes.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_construct_from_string for more.  The Boost docs can be a little intimidating as there is so much detail. You want Gregorian Date for the date, and Duration for the difference -- or work from an existing example like the one I posted.

Comment: I'm getting ```ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘difference’ with no type```

Comment: ```days x = y - z``` (```y``` and ```z``` are ```date```)